# How to default the value of a lookup column from another forms text field

Tags: lookup-column, default-value

I have two SharePoint lists. List A (Incidents), which includes an incident number, List B (Subjects), which includes a Lookup Column that uses the incident number. List B allows multiple subjects to be listed for each incident.[image: Form A]

In PowerApps I have a form to input the details for List A (See image above). Incident number generated on a new entry is circled in red. A button takes you to another screen with a second form to input details for List B (See image below). The lookup field is circled in red. When creating a new form for List B, I'd like the Lookup value to default to the incident number entered on List A. I've been trying different methods to accomplish this and haven't been able to crack the code yet.[image: Form B]

Comment: Are you using drop down control or combo box control for "SIR Lookup" field? Does this allow single entry or multiple entries to select? Try setting `Default` property of control based on selection in the first gallery item. For example: `Gallery1.Selected.SerialReportNumber`. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: I believe its a combo box control that allows a single selection. I tried your example and it gives the following error: Expected record value

Comment: What is the formula used for data source (items) property of "SIR Lookup" field?

Comment: The data source is List B

Comment: Whole list or are you selecting single column values from the list?

Comment: I tried this formula: If(SubjectForm.Mode = FormMode.New, {Value: Gallery1.Selected.'SerialReportNumber'}, Parent.Default) and it worked to show the value I wanted. But in testing, although it shows in the combo box, its not saving back to List B with the value. Instead it leaves it blank back on the list.

Comment: Check the `Update` property of related "data card" control (parent control of combo box) - it should be updated with the correct selected value in the combo box in order to save it in the list.

Comment: The update property says 'DataCardValue15.Selected'. Are you saying it should be RecordsGalery1.Selected?